# iPad CSS Page Width

Tags: ipad, html, css

I'm having some issues with my page and header on the iPad vs desktop.

When you look at http://www.photopile.me on the computer, the pictures and header/footer should stretch 100% of the way to the edge.
[image]

When you go to it on the iPad, it doesn't show the full width of the page and the 100% header gets resized. I'd like the ipad to show the full width of the page.
[image]

I'm just getting started optimizing for iPad, but what am I missing?  I'm sure there's a stupid little rule I'm missing.  Here is the header HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        ... header content ...
    </div>
</header>
<div id="page-content">
        .... photos ....
</div>
```

and CSS

```
header {
    background: url('../images/header-bg.jpg') repeat-x top left;
    z-index: 500;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#header-wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#page-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 400;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 91px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope that's enough info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@brenden,

write `min-width:1024px;` instead of `min-width:1180px;` in the `#wrapper` because it's a problem of your PC also. Check yourself.

Comment: this still doesn't fix the iPad issue. When it loads, especially vertical, the spacing is all off

Comment: @brenden, the ipad dimension is 1024 x 768 .So, you can give min-width:768px . Actual it is a issue of min-width.

Answer (score 13):

You may look into the zoom control via meta tags.  I had some issues with this recently when the iPad was scaling up my page and I didn't realize it. (which caused me to inadvertently develop with incorrect sizing)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Possible values:

- `initial-scale`
- `max-scale`
- `min-scale`
- `user-scalable`
- `width`
- `height`

You can read up more on it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html